# How to get range of hour using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to extract data with intervals of 1 hour in my log file. Here is my variables:

date_file=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H"`
 date_minus_one=`date -d "-1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%d %H"`
 date_minus_two=`date -d "-2 hour" +"%Y-%m-%d %H"`

Here's my syntax in awk but it always print all the data.

```
awk '$date_file >= $date_minus_one && $date_file <= $date_minus_two' <filename>
```

I've also use grep in getting an interval of 1 hour but it didn't work.

Here's a sample data I want to extract per hour data:

```
2016-03-30|00:54:46,060|[WARNING]
2016-03-30|00:55:46,318|[OK]
2016-03-30|00:55:46,318|[OK]
2016-03-30|02:42:13,691|[UNKNOWN]
2016-03-30|07:53:16,356|[CRITICAL]
2016-03-30|08:56:41,410|[WARNING]
```

Answer (score 0):

The output from date is a string and has a space in it -- I.e.

```
$ date -d "-2 hour" +"%Y-%m-%d %H"
2016-03-20 18
```

So it needs to be quoted to be able to compare it against something in the file.

```
awk '"$date_file" >= "$date_minus_one" && "$date_file" <= "$date_minus_two"'
```

That would solve some of the problem, **BUT** according to your description $date_file, $date_minus_one etc are constants, so **nothing** will change during execution, and the expression will either always be true or always be false.

Comment: What can I do to make it always true?so that I can get a per hour data with my file.

Comment: @RobertJohnMartin crontab?

Comment: @RobertJohnMartin -- we don't know what your files look like, so that is impossible to answer -- update your question adding examples of the filenames and examples of the file content